# run spark-class on yarn-standalone mode and got error with file changed on src filesystem

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I just started to program with Spark 0.9 on yarn-standalone mode. I run program use this:

> spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client       --jar $SPARK_HOME/count.jar       --class WordCountJava       --args yarn-standalone   --args hdfs://10.1.1.33:9000/user/root/test.txt   --args hdfs://10.1.1.33:9000/out/ik       --num-workers 3       --master-memory 4g       --worker-memory 2g       --worker-cores 1

if i login as **root account**, the program can **run well**. But if I login as "luzy" a **normal account**, the program run **failed**, and got error like this:

> appDiagnostics: Application application_1395994477084_0040 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1395994477084_0040_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/usr/app/spark-0.9.0/count.jar changed on src filesystem (expected 1395762200000, was 1395993910000
>   .Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.

what should I do to solve it?